# Basic implicit query

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, and trying to get my head around implicit wizardry. I want to understand why I am getting `2mysize` with `+` function and the `2 *` the length for `*` function?

```
   implicit def addToStr(str: String) = str.size


    scala> 2 * "mysize"

    res4: Int = 12

    scala> 2 + "mysize"

    res3: String = 2mysize
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [ScalaDocs page for the `Int`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html) API. The `Int` class has a `+()` method for adding a `String`.

```
abstract def +(x: String): String
```

But it has no `*()` method for multiplying a `String`. The compiler will always choose a defined function/method over an implicit. It will only go looking for an implicit solution as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

***Implicit Conversions are only applied if the expression doesn't match the argument type of the function.***

Example:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
implicit def strToInt(s: String):Int = s.size
def printStr(s: Int):Unit = {
  println(s"Printing Int ${s}")
}

printStr("SSSS")
```

In the above case, the implicit method comes into picture, but if you define another method as shown below.

```
def printStr(s: String) = {
  println(s"Printing String ${s}")
}
```

It will automatically use this method rather than implicit resolutions.
https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3911.html